# SVG images are not showing in reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs

i want to create svg shapes dynamically and append it to dom using react
here is the jsfiddle link

[Svg shapes are not displaying in react](http:////jsfiddle.net/asifjavedg3/qfcv0fo2/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the goal is to draw a cat then the problem is that your `d:` properties is full of new lines thus making it not being a valid SVG path.

Check your console and you'll see the error `Uncaught SyntaxError: embedded: Unterminated string constant`.

[Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/qfcv0fo2/1/)